# “I had been thinking of” or ”I thought about“

Tags: past-simple, perfect-constructions

Is the following correct:

> I **thought** about killing myself for a couple of hours after **I swallowed** the pill.

or do I have to change it to:

> **I had been thinking** of killing myself for a couple of hours after I **swallowed** the pill.

Comment: What do you think Costas. Which version do you prefer - and why?

Comment: If this is true, regardless of grammar, you need to get help. Maybe we can help.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct.

The second sentence would only be correct if you used "before" instead of "after".